# Serialized JSON is not deserializing

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've got some JSON code I'm embedding in a JSON object that I use JsonConvert . SerializeObject ( ) to properly escape for myself, then I promptly try JsonConvert.DeserializeObject ( ) and get an error.

`Error converting value "{ "ID_3DCS": "3F", "Name": "3Form", "EXT_ID": "1", "FreeShippingLevel": null, "TaxRate": null, "CurrencyRate": null, "CurrencyCode": "USD", "LeadTime": null }" to type 'SortlyBridge.SortlyBridge+Vendor'. Path '', line 1, position 184.`

```
sortlyObject . notes = JsonConvert . SerializeObject ( @"{ ""ID_3DCS"": """ + id_3dcs + @""", ""Name"": """ + name + @""", ""EXT_ID"": """ + ext_id + @""", ""FreeShippingLevel"": " + freeShippingLevel . ToString ( @"" , "null" ) + @", ""TaxRate"": " + taxRate . ToString ( @"" , "null" ) + @", ""CurrencyRate"": " + currencyRate . ToString ( @"" , "null" ) + @", ""CurrencyCode"": """ + currencyCode . ToUpper ( ) + @""", ""LeadTime"": " + leadTime . ToString ( @"" , "null" ) + @" }" );

Vendor test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <Vendor> ( sortlyObject . notes );
```

The string that came out of JsonConvert.SeralizeObject is:

```
"{ \"ID_3DCS\": \"3F\", \"Name\": \"3Form\", \"EXT_ID\": \"1\", \"FreeShippingLevel\": null, \"TaxRate\": null, \"CurrencyRate\": null, \"CurrencyCode\": \"USD\", \"LeadTime\": null }"
```

sortlyObject is a class to wrap JSON.
notes is a string field I want to store JSON in.

I've tried using blanks for the nulls, that didn't parse either so I created my own extension for the decimal?.ToString() to return null, as well as int?.ToString() to return null.

I'm expecting it to parse correctly.

Comment: You're not serializing a `Vendor` object, you're serializing a string of pseudo-JSON. Don't do that; just create a `Vendor` instance and serialize that.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I need to encapsulate this in JSON, that's why I was trying to serialize the pseudo-JSON.  Do I double Serialize it?  I'm getting an error in from my API trying to just serialize the Vendor object.

Comment: The *string that came out of JsonConvert.SeralizeObject* looks like double-serialized JSON.  I.e. you serialized some model to a JSON string, then serialized that string to JSON a second time.  Might you please confirm that this your JSON is really double-serialized?  Additionally, please [edit] your question to share a complete [mcve] that we can run and debug, as suggested in [ask].

Comment: Ok I did as @HereticMonkey suggested, and Serialized a Vendor Object, then Serialized that result to get it to work in the embedded JSON.  Thank you, I'm not sure how to mark this as the solution.  Thanks dbc for the suggestion on double-serialized, by double-deserializing I confirmed that it would parse correctly.

Comment: I guess you need to think about why the double serialization is happening in the first place. Note by the way that JSON use the text `null` to represent null, not an empty string.

Comment: Your json string is ok. If you need some help you have to post 'SortlyBridge.SortlyBridge+Vendor" class

Answer (score 0):

Simply do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Vendor>(jsonString)`, where jsonString is

```cs
string jsonString = @"{ ""ID_3DCS"": """ + id_3dcs + @""", ""Name"": """ + name + @""", ""EXT_ID"": """ + ext_id + @""", ""FreeShippingLevel"": " + freeShippingLevel . ToString ( @"" , "null" ) + @", ""TaxRate"": " + taxRate . ToString ( @"" , "null" ) + @", ""CurrencyRate"": " + currencyRate . ToString ( @"" , "null" ) + @", ""CurrencyCode"": """ + currencyCode . ToUpper ( ) + @""", ""LeadTime"": " + leadTime . ToString ( @"" , "null" ) + @" }"
```

Skip `SerializeObject`, simply deserialize the jsonString, and you should get `Vendor` successfully.